# How to code this math integrate?

Tags: python, math

My math skills are really poor.
I'm trying to handle accelerometer data (tri-axis) with Python
I need to compute the norm

[image: norm]

That is easy I made something like that:

```
math.sqrt(x_value**2 + y_value**2 + z_value**2)
```

but now, I have to compute the integration of that:

[image: integration]

And for that I have no clue..
Can somebody help me on that?

---

Edit: Adding more info due to the negative votes (??)
I know there are tools to make integrations in python, but this one is not with edges (there are no limits in the formula) So that, I don't understand how to make it works..

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/tutorial/integrate.html

Comment: See trapezoid and Simpson rule of numerical integration, provided the samples are equally spaced.

Comment: @LutzL thanks! It helps

Comment: integral over t? Are you sure it’s **dt**? Because there’s is no `t` in the integral body, so that `a`-squared thing is a constant.

Comment: It seems that a is an acceleration vector at time t. The missing part is your input data. Where do you get a from ?

Comment: @Gribouillis I have a Collection of x,y,z values over time:
T1,x1,y1,z1
T2,x2,y2,z2
...

Comment: Then you can create a collection of norm over time by computing the norm of each item. If the times are equally spaced, your integral is nothing but a cumsum

Answer (score 0):

Integrating the modulus of the acceleration will lead you nowhere. You must integrate all three components separately to get the components of the speed (and integrate them a second time to get the position vector).

To perform the numerical integration, use the Simpson rule incrementally. Anyway, as the number of points must be even, you will only get every other value of the speed.